# Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell error

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-poi, xssf

I have tried many SO answers on this regard but still I could not resolve.
My java file is as follows:

```
public class ReadExcelFileAndStore {

    public List getTheFileAsObject(String filePath){
        List <Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            //System.out.println(numberOfSheets);
            //loop through each of the sheets
           for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {

               String sheetName = workbook.getSheetName(i);
               System.out.println(sheetName);
               // Get first sheet from the workbook
               XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);


               // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
               Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
               while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                   // Get Each Row
                   Row row = rowIterator.next();

                   //Leaving the first row alone as it is header
                   if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                       continue;
                   }
                   // For each row, iterate through each columns
                   Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                   Employee employee = new Employee();

                   while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();


                        int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

                        switch (columnIndex + 1) {

                            case 1:
                                employee.setEmpName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                employee.setExtCode((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                employee.setDepartment(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    employeeList.add(employee);
                }
            }
            file.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return employeeList;
    }
}
```

I have the model as follows:

```
package com.restfapi.demo.Model;

public class Employee {

    private String empName;
    private int extCode;
    private String department;

    public Employee(){
    }

    public Employee(String empName,int extCode, String department){
        this.empName = empName;
        this.extCode = extCode;
        this.department = department;
    }

    //all getters and setters are followed
}
```

This problem is because the header of extCode is string and the values in that column are integers. Even if I skip the header and read the rest, the error appears.When I changed the datatype of extCode to String the error is reversed and getting "Cannot get a STRING cell from a NUMERIC cell". Please somebody help me to get rid of this error

Comment: In case 2 in your `getTheFileAsObject()` method, try doing `employee.setExtCode(Integer.parseInt(cell.getStringCellValue()));`
From the look of things, you are trying to get a Numberic value from a cell which is a String.

Comment: No. Still I am getting the same error!

Comment: Can you add a paste link to a stack trace? Ideally if your cell value is numerical then it should work as suggested.

Comment: Do your columns have headings? Can you paste a link to a sample spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Put a check when you are getting value from the cell. It should be something like below.

```
case 2:
    if(cell. getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC){
        employee.setExtCode((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }else{
    employee.setExtCode(Integer.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue()));
    }
    break;
```

There are several supported cell type POI API. For more info visit the [link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html#NUMERIC)

Edited:

If the above solution not work you can simply do

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); 
employee.setExtCode(Integer.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue()));
```

Before reading the value from the cell. However, [POI documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-) clearly says to use **setCellType** to read the value from a cell as you might be lost original formatting of the cell. Instead of using that you can use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). The code should be like below (I did not complied and run).

```
String strValue = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
```

Comment: this does not work. i have tried this out already. I am getting the same error still. suggest me some other ideas please!

Comment: @hema I have edited my answer. Please go through it, it may help you.